# TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes) when running server

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, git-bash

I am attempting to run a Python Flask server in Git Bash. When running this server outside of Git Bash, I use PyCharm and I have no issues. However, I am attempting to deploy my program into a server and am using Git Bash for that. I have done everything else perfectly and running the server in Git Bash is the last step required in my deployment. I believe the error is my Python version and I am following a tutorial video where in the video, the user is using Python 3.6.9 while my Git Bash, by default, is using Python 3.8.10. I have tried to change my Git Bash python version down to 3.6.9 but I have not found a good tutorial or steps on how to do that.

Requirement.txt has:

```
Flask==1.0.2
numpy==1.20.0
scikit-learn==0.20.3
```

[This is the error I get when attempting to run my server.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjENT.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

EDIT: I got it to work after simply updating the scikit-learn module to version 0.24.1

Comment: This error has nothing to do with Git and probably nothing to do with git-bash either. It seems to be coming from a scikit-learn dependency, specifically from `externals/joblib/cloudpickle/`, although that might be triggered by something else in turn. Make sure your packages are compatible with that version of Python, or select a version of Python that does support them.

Comment: You could answer your own question and accept it to mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Updating scikit-learn module to version 0.24.1 solves this issue